# iOS Push Notifications not showing images

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm having trouble displaying an image in push notifications. Initially, my "identifier" was not unique, which posed the risk of my "attachments" being overwritten. I have now made the identifier unique, but as a result, the image no longer shows up in push notifications. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Also I did create a Notification Service Extension and also I been using Postman to push the notifications to my actual device using google firebase.

**View Controller**

```
import UserNotifications
import UIKit
import UserNotificationsUI

class ImagePushNotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // The code first checks if the notification content has an attachment.
    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
        let content = notification.request.content

        if let attachment = content.attachments.first,
            attachment.url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(),
            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: attachment.url),
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            self.imageView.image = image
            attachment.url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationService**

```
import UserNotifications

protocol ImageLoader {
    func downloadImageData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void)
}

class DefaultImageLoader: ImageLoader {
    func downloadImageData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(data)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

class NotificationModifier {
    let imageLoader: ImageLoader

    init(imageLoader: ImageLoader) {
        self.imageLoader = imageLoader
    }

    func addAttachment(_ content: UNMutableNotificationContent, contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        guard let urlString = content.userInfo["image"] as? String,
              let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString)
        else {
            contentHandler(content)
            return
        }

        downloadImageData(from: fileUrl) { imageData in
            if let data = imageData {
                let fileIdentifier = "image.jpg"

                if let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk(
                    fileIdentifier: fileIdentifier, data: data, options: nil
                ) {
                    content.attachments = [attachment]
                    content.title = "\(content.title)"

                    // Delete the attachment file
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: attachment.url)
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed to delete attachment file: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
            contentHandler(content)
        }
    }

    func downloadImageData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        imageLoader.downloadImageData(from: url, completion: completion)
    }
}

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        let imageLoader = DefaultImageLoader()
        let notificationModifier = NotificationModifier(imageLoader: imageLoader)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            notificationModifier.addAttachment(bestAttemptContent, contentHandler: contentHandler)
        } else {
            if let content = request.content.copy() as? UNNotificationContent {
                contentHandler(content)
            }
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    static func saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: String, data: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let folderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let folderURL = fileManager.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)

        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

            let uniqueIdentifier = "\(fileIdentifier)_\(data.hashValue)"
            let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(uniqueIdentifier)

            try data.write(to: fileURL, options: [])
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: uniqueIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
            return attachment
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```